# aws cognito static website and verify token in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto, amazon-cognito

im trying to secure a static website on aws s3 with cognito. i thought of following architecture:

static website PAGE1 with javascript cognito sdk in a public bucket. This bucket is public availabe and has a login site which is connected
to cognito identity provider with a user pool also in cognito. there i ask the user for login and MFA token sent by cognito. this is already working.
i receive a JWT Token with access, id, and refresh token.

now comes the part i do not fully understand. i read a lot of the documentation, but couldnt get a solution. maybe my assumptions are wrong:

i POST the JWT to a python lambda in the API Gateway. This Lambda should verify the token ( how??? ), and if it is valid, i return PAGE2 which is in a private bucket.
but boto3 doesnt offer a method like „validate_token“. i also dont want to assume a role or so, i just want lambda to validate the token and then return PAGE2.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction. is this the right use case for cognito? how can i validate that the token is a valid token from cognito and not expired?

Comment: I think it's better if you can separate the private content like html and js/css separated so that you can make html only private and read by lambda and returned while js/css downloaded directly from browser. For validating the Cognito token, if you use Cognito & API Gateway JS sdks at browser client, you just have to set IAM authorization at API gateway for the authorizer which will validate the token.

Comment: Did you figure out this issue yet? Or still struggling?

Comment: no, there is no out of the box solution and i didnt have time to do research in the poor documentation. anyway, we changed the architecure and decided to make our own authorization. cognito is good for users in an app, but imho not very useful when it comes to users which use resources in an account.